# Not sending userAgent in header, Node.js console application

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, console, request

I'm just beginning to learn javascript and https requests.  I'm working in Visual Studio 2017, I created a blank javascript console app from the template and added the following code.

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
    hostname: 'api.gdax.com',
    path: '/products/BTC-USD/stats',
    method: 'GET',
    agent: false
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```

The response I get from the server is

```
{"message":"User-Agent header is required."}
```

When I navigate to https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/stats in my browser I get the correct response.  How come I can't do the same in a javascript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because that specific API is blocking any request without the User-Agent header.

Just add the header, and it will work fine:

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'api.gdax.com',
  path: '/products/BTC-USD/stats',
  method: 'GET',
  agent: false,
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'something',
  },
};

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on('error', e => {
  console.error(e);
});
req.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set headers manually.  See [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) documentation for all possible request options (this is the same for `http` and `https`).

try:

```
const options = {
    hostname: 'api.gdax.com',
    path: '/products/BTC-USD/stats',
    method: 'GET',
    agent: false,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Foo/1.0',
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitely set the `User-Agent` header in the `headers` property of your request `options`

```
const options = {
    hostname: 'api.gdax.com',
    path: '/products/BTC-USD/stats',
    method: 'GET',
    agent: false,
    headers: { 'User-Agent': 'Mosaic/1.0' }
};
```